# Criar tabela de parcelas dinamicamente com jquery?

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho um select com quantidade de parcelas, e gostaria de adicionar as linhas na tabela dinamicamente com a quantidade de parcelas selecionadas.
exemplo:

```js
$('#simular').click(function(){
        $('#table').show();
        var parcelas = 4; //simulando 4 parcelas
        var total = 4750.00; //simulando este valor
        var table;
        var x = 1;
        while(x <= parcelas){
            table += '<tr><td> de </td>';
            table += '<td>data</td>';
            table += '<td>$valor</td></tr>';    
            //$('#table tbody').prepend(table); comentei o código pois está dando timeout
        }        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="simular">Simular</button>
<table id="table" style="display:none;">
  <tr>
    <th>parcela</th>
    <th>valor</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

já faz umas 2 horas que estou parado aqui e já fiz tantos ajustes que não consigo pensar em uma solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de incrementar o `x` senão ficas num loop infinito...

```js
$('#simular').click(function() {
  $('#table').show();
  var parcelas = 4; //simulando 4 parcelas
  var total = 4750.00; //simulando este valor
  var table = '';
  var x = 1;
  while (x <= parcelas) {
    table += '<tr><td>' + x + '</td>';
    table += '<td>data</td>';
    table += '<td>$valor</td></tr>';
    x++;
  }
  $('#table tbody').html(table);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="simular">Simular</button>
<table id="table" style="display:none;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>parcela</th>
      <th>data</th>
      <th>valor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: cometi um erro primário, obrigado pela sua ajuda.

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso de nada, fico contente de ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar o DOM para incluir as linhas, acho que é mais fácil e é dinâmico também. Segue um exemplo:

```
    var table = document.getElementById("tbResumo");
    var row = table.tBodies[0].insertRow();

    var colCodigo = row.insertCell(0);
    var colDescricao = row.insertCell(1);
    var colLote = row.insertCell(2);
    var colQuantidade = row.insertCell(3);

    colCodigo.innerHTML = element.CodProduto;
    colDescricao.innerHTML = element.NomeProduto;
    colLote.innerHTML = element.Lote;
    colQuantidade.innerHTML = element.Quantidade;
```